# Customize automatically generated TOC on jekyll/kramdown site

Tags: jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I have a Jekyll site that uses kramdown for markdown. In `_config.yml` I have the following setting that ensures that only `<h2>` and `<h3>` elements show up in the automatically generated table of contents:

```
kramdown: 
  toc_levels: "2,3"
```

This works fine, but on some pages I would like to include `<h4>` elements in the TOC as well, while retaining the existing `<h2>` and `<h3>` configuration on other pages. Is this possible?

On any page I can access the `_config.yml` definitions like this:

```
{{ site.kramdown.toc_levels }}
```

Is there a way to *set* the value of the `toc_levels` on a page?

Comment: I realize I can use the {:.no_toc} option to suppress inclusion of individual tags, but am looking for a page-level setting in this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked through the codes. It appears page-level settings are not possible for Kramdown at this moment. You are left with {:.no_toc} option to suppress unexpected tags.